# My shifters are stuck in the negatives

Tags: gears, stuck

So I recently bought my first bike. It worked great until winter hit. The gears stopped working and my girlfriend (who bikes way more that I do) said they so that when it gets really cold sometimes and the issue would resolve itself when it got hotter. It is now way above freezing and it still hasn’t resolved itself. The odd part about it is that the shifters are not able to go above the first gear but is instead able to go in reverse (to what would be gear 0 and -1). I’ve done some googling without results and I am honestly just very confused. Any tips on what could have happened and any potential fixes (no fancy bike lingo btw please)

Comment: Take side and edge-on pictures of the mechanism that moves the chain from gear to gear, which is called a "derailleur." I think _either_ your problem is shifter cable tension _or_ something is bent.

Comment: Please add photos to your question, using [edit]   Does the derailleur move properly if you pull the exposed inner cable ?  Is this a problem inside the shifter on the handlebar?   Do you store your bike outside in the weather ?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what gear 0 or -1 would be.

Assuming your shifters have a ratcheting mechanism in them, and assuming there's grease in there, the grease may have gotten stickier in the cold, and the ratchet pawls failed to unstick when it warmed up. Shooting some WD40 in there might help. But without knowing more about your bike, it's hard to even speculate.

If there's a bike shop in your area, you can take it to them.